How I can change the country name on my profile in portal.ustraveldocs.com?
I applied for an online USA visit visa (B1/B2) with my family and filled the online DS-160 forms and received the confirmations. I applied on portal.ustraveldocs.com to deposit the visa fees and get the interview waiver letter as I am applying within 48 months of my previous visa's expiration date, but my email IDs were mistakenly registered in Latvia.
How can I change my country name in my profile in portal.ustraveldocs.com?

Does this answer your question? How can I change my visa appointment to another country?

Not a duplicate. This question is about changing the applicant’s home country name on a non-US government visa application site, while the other addresses a change of appt locations.

@DavidRecallsMonica It's all the one concept

@DavidRecallsMonica Ustraveldocs is the official US Visa application website for most countries

@NicolasFormichella Thanks for the info; I didn't know that. Still, I'm not persuaded: a change in home country ID (this question) is not the same as changing the location of a visa appointment (the asserted-as-duplicate question).

Visit the "Contact Us" page on ustraveldocs.com. I suggest you send them an email, providing your complete name along with the passport number and DS-160 confirmation number. Clearly state there was an error in registration for Latvia instead of USA; kindly ask to alter this mistake by changing it to United States. To have quicker outcome, try phoning their support number mentioned on the site and have all your details prepared. If calling takes too much time, make a fresh profile with the correct country using another electronic mail address. Once it’s fixed, double-check everything and re-submit if needed. Good luck!
